# dynamic vertical multi column list does not work in IE

Tags: html, css, list, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Blow code works perfectly for Mozilla, Safari & Chrome but not in IE 7,8,9.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css"> 
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;float:left;}

.column {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 8px;
    width:40%;
}
label{
   float:left;
}
ul li a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
ul li {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;  
    overflow:hidden;
}
.column {
/* the proper rules ready for future */
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 20px;

/* Moz/Firefox rules */
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 20px;

/* Safari & Chrome rules */
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="column">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"></label>Francoise Barre-Sinoussi</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"></label>Rachel Carson</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"></label>Shirley M. Tilghman</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"></label>Jane Goodall</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Marie Curie</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Rosalind Franklin</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Svetlana Savitskaya</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Mae Jemison</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Mayim Bialik</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Sally Ride</li>
</ul>
</body> 
</html>
```

What hack i will have to apply to make it working in IE7,8 & 9.

Comment: What does this have to to with php? Please retag to HTML.

Comment: To clarify, the problem is the `column-count: 3;`

Comment: @falsarella: Can you please also suggest the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code,

```
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;float:left;}

.column {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #999;
padding: 8px;
width:500px;
}
ul li {
float:left;
margin: 0 0 5px 0;  
overflow:hidden;
width: 200px;
background-color: orange;
margin-right: 10px;
}
.column {
/* the proper rules ready for future */
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 20px;

/* Moz/Firefox rules */
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 20px;

/* Safari & Chrome rules */
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Zcecm Try here and let me know if it is work or not.

Comment: It works now. It was `width:40%;` in your post instead of `width:500px;`.

Comment: Just to make it clear. It works because of the `ul li` width with 200px and `.column` with 500px, wich would fit 2 times. To have 3 columns as the column-count: 3, the width of `.column` should be 3 times the width of `ul li` (600px, for example).

Answer (score 0):

IE does not support the CSS `column-count`.

The only solution I see is changing the html structure and css:

*[See the jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BBSUb/4/)*

HTML:

```
<div class="border">
<ul class="column">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"></label>Francoise Barre-Sinoussi</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"></label>Rachel Carson</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"></label>Shirley M. Tilghman</li>
</ul>
<ul class="column">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox"></label>Jane Goodall</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Marie Curie</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Rosalind Franklin</li>
</ul>
<ul class="column">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Svetlana Savitskaya</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Mae Jemison</li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Mayim Bialik</li>

</ul>
<ul class="column">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" ></label>Sally Ride</li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;float:left;}

.column {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
}
.border {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    float: left;
}
label{
   float:left;
}
ul li a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
ul li {
    clear:both;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;  
}
```